# React Native Release Signed APK crash on app start time

Tags: react-native

I have an issue with react native release APK.

The app run on debug mode but it crash immediately on release mode
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Is that app running without any warnings/errors before building the APK?
The error message clearly says that it can't find a variable, maybe it got deleted or modified.
You can cross-check the app once by going to the development mode and see if you get the same error.

Comment: We are not getting any other error in development mode. its only in signed apk

Comment: Maybe you have to open the bundle and go to the referenced line to see what's there or missing. Because there's no other info available.

Answer (score 0):

Try out clean your gradle and make the apk again.